# How to solve $f(x) = \text{A}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{\text{B}_i}\Bigl(1-\exp\Bigl(-\frac{x}{\text{C}_i}\Bigl)\Bigl)$ for $x$?

Tags: calculus

I've given the following equation

$$
f(x) = \text{A}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{\text{B}_i}\Bigl(1-\exp\Bigl(-\frac{x}{\text{C}_i}\Bigr)\Bigr)
$$

where $\text{A}$, $\text{B}_i$ and $\text{C}_i$ are real constants > 0. For a given value of $f(x)$ I now want to determine $x$.

If $i=1$, then there's a simple analytical solution possible.

It seems to me that if $i>1$ this is not longer the case and the equation has to be solved numerically. - Is that true? Or is ist possible to solve this equation analytically for $x$ when $i>1$?

If there doesn't exist an analytical solution which numerical method would you suggest to use in order to Keep the numbers of iterations low?

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No analytical method exists when you have more than one term, and in particular with 6 terms.

But, have you noticed that, for all $x$, the derivative $f'(x)>0$ ? Thus, function $f$ is (strictly) increasing from $-\infty$ to $L:=A\sum_{i=1}^{6}\tfrac{1}{B_i}$ which is the limit of $f(x)$ when $x \to \infty$ (see graphics below).

Thus, if you fix a value $y_0$, and look for an $x$ such that

$$\tag{1}f(x)=y_0,$$

2 cases are to be considered:

- if $y_0 \geq L$, there is no solution $x$ to (1).
- otherwise, there is a unique solution that you can reach by successive bracketings, in a similar manner as you would do for **bisection method**:

Find at first a large negative value $a_1$ and a large positive value $b_1$ such that $f(a_1) < y_0 < f(b_1)$.

Then set $m=(a_1+b_1)/2$ ; compute $f(m)$ : if $f(m)<y_0$ set $a_2=m, b_2=b_1$ otherwise, set $a_2=a_1, b_2=m$.

Iterate these operations until $b_n-a_n<10^{-2}$ for example.

[image]

Graphical representation of function $f(x)=(1-e^{-x/A})/B+(1-e^{-x/C})/D+(1-e^{-x/E})/F)$ with $A=0.3, B=0.1, C=0.6, D=0.6, E=0.3, F=0.3$, with asymptote $L=\dfrac{1}{B}+\dfrac{1}{D}+\dfrac{1}{F}=15$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jean Marie for your answer, it is very clear and understandable to me.

Comment: I think it should be possible to adapt the procedure straight Forward to my case, where - for example - $f(x) = (1-e^{(-(T-x)/A)})/B+(1-e^{(-(T-x)/C)})/D$ is ... (T is as well a given constant.)

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the best case where $C_i=\frac ai$; Change variable $x=-a \log(y)$ and 
$$f(x) = A\,\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{{B}_i}\Bigl(1-\exp\Bigl(-\frac{x}{{C}_i}\Bigr)\Bigr)$$ becomes $$g(y)=A\,\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{{B}_i}-A \,\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{y^i}{{B}_i}$$ which is a polynomial of degree $6$ ... that you cannot solve.

As Jean Marie answered, only numerical methods would do the job.